# Would you give me advice for Quick Action Handling using by LWC and Aura?

Tags: lightning-web-components

[image]

The picture is structure in my requiring information.

I want to handling information when captured validate method or throw exception on Apex Controller connected by LWC, Close quick action (= Aura Container) on screen.

In currently, completed showing message that Aura Handled Exception, but still cannot close Quick Action Sereen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Dispatch a `CustomEvent` from LWC Child Component to Parent Aura Component when you receive the exception from Apex. Then you have to catch the event in Aura Component and fire the `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction")` to close the Quick Action.

*At high level the code will look as below*

*LWC HTML*

```xml
<template>
    <h1>quickActionLwcAura</h1>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Close" title="Primary action" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
</template>
```

*LWC JS*

```javascript
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
export default class QuickActionLwcAura extends LightningElement {
    handleClick(event) {
        const value = event.target.value;
        const valueChangeEvent = new CustomEvent("closeaction", {
            detail: { value }
        });
        // Fire the custom event
        this.dispatchEvent(valueChangeEvent);
    }
}
```

*Aura Cmp*

```xml
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction" >
    Parent Aura Component:
    <c:quickActionLwcAura oncloseaction = "{!c.closequickaction}"/>
</aura:component>
```

*Aura JS*

```javascript
({
    closequickaction : function(component, event, helper) {
        var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire();
    }
})
```